# What is a word for someone who knows where to hit another where it hurts?

Tags: single-word-requests

By 'knows where to hit someone where it hurts' I mean someone who uses another person's weaknesses and feelings to their advantage. Say if their opponent had low self esteem about a certain part of their body the person would make sure to bring it up in the argument to weaken their opponent.

Comment: Sounds like a _shrewd_ person. But really, for [single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info), you need to give an example sentence with a blank where this word would go. You may want to take a site [tour] too. Welcome to ELU.SE, by the way.

Comment: A psychopath would do this but I'm not sure if that's specific enough.

Comment: If the person is *able* to find their opponents weaknesses, then as alwayslearning says, they are shrewd, or cunning. If they are *willing* to use their opponents weaknesses, then they are ruthless, merciless or one of the many synonyms.

Comment: *Button pusher*.

Comment: ......*Sadist.*

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [word](http://www.yourdictionary.com/gaslighter) "[gaslighter](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/here-there-and-everywhere/201701/gaslighting-know-it-and-identify-it-protect-yourself)":

> Gaslighting is a tactic in which a person or entity, in order to gain
>   more power, makes a victim question their reality. It works much
>   better than you may think. Anyone is susceptible to gaslighting, and
>   it is a common technique of abusers, dictators, narcissists, and cult
>   leaders. It is done slowly, so the victim doesn't realize how much
>   they've been brainwashed.

and a gaslighter is:

> One who engages in the psychological tactic of gaslighting.

If online, you can use the word ["griefer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Griefer):

> A griefer is a player in a multiplayer video game who deliberately
>   irritates and angers other players within the game, often using
>   aspects of the game in unintended ways. A griefer derives pleasure
>   primarily or exclusively from the act of annoying other users, and as
>   such is a particular nuisance in online gaming communities, since
>   griefers often cannot be deterred by penalties related to in-game
>   goals.